# Back to Index Button

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with 208 sheets and a summary sheet. Want to create a button to jump to each sheet. i am using the below codes for that.

```
Sub SearchSheetName()

Dim xName As String
Dim xFound As Boolean

xName = InputBox("Enter sheet name to find in workbook:", "Sheet search")
If xName = "" Then Exit Sub

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(xName).Select
xFound = (Err = 0)
On Error GoTo 0

If xFound Then
    MsgBox "Sheet '" & xName & "' has been found and selected!"
Else
    MsgBox "The sheet '" & xName & "' could not be found in this workbook!"
End If

End Sub
```

Going back to Summary sheet is difficult. so created macro with button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("SummarySheet").Select

End Sub
```

is there any easy way to create this button  in all the sheets together.

Comment: Select all of the worksheets and use the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F).

Comment: I use the Microsoft Custom UI editor to add buttons to the ribbon. Very slick for an applications such as this.

Answer (score 1):

I will add a button or shape (they are more pleasing in terms of cosmetics) to the sheet dynamically when its activated. Use Workbook's SheetActivate event to apply this to all the worksheets in the workbook.

In the WorkBook's SheetActivate add this

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Call addButton
End Sub
```

VBA code in a standard module:

```
Sub addButton()

    '/ Dynamically add a semi-transparent shape on the active sheet.
    '/ Call this inside workbooks SheetActivate event

    Dim shp As Shape

    Const strButtonName As String = "BackButton"

    '/ Dont't add on summary sheet.
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary" Then Exit Sub


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '/ Delete if old shape exists
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Name = strButtonName Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 330.75, 36.75, 93.75, 29.25).Select
    Selection.Name = "BackButton"

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(strButtonName)

    '/ Some formatting for the shape.
    With shp
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Summary"
        .Top = 3
        .Left = 3
        .Fill.Transparency = 0.6
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 112, 192)
        .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

        '/ Add the macro to shape's click. This will active summary sheet.
        shp.OnAction = "goBack"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub goBack()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: why add the button everytime the sheet activates (and remove it before if already exsits)?I think you should create a one-time macro that performs a loop through all the sheets of the workbook and creates the button with the code of @cyboashu for each sheet (except the summary one) once...Done the job, you have your buttons, stop.

Comment: Hi Ettore , could you please help me with the above said codes if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Table of Contents (TOC) question.  Copy/paste the code below and see if it does essentially what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim TOC As String
Dim msg As String
Dim fc_order As Range
Dim fc_alphabet As Range
Dim sht As Object
TOC = "Table of Contents"

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  If Worksheets(i).Name = TOC Then
  msg = Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Your sheet " & Chr(10) & TOC & Chr(10) & "(now displayed) will be updated."
  Worksheets(TOC).Activate
  Exit For
  Else
  msg = "A new sheet will be added :" & TOC & ", with hyperlinks to all sheets in this workbook."
  End If
Next i
If MsgBox(msg & Chr(10) & "Do you want to continue ?", 36, TOC) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If ActiveSheet.Name = TOC Then Worksheets(TOC).Delete
Worksheets(1).Activate
Worksheets.Add.Name = TOC
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
With Cells(2, 6)
.Value = UCase(TOC)
.Font.Size = 18
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter 'verspreid over blad breedte
End With

Set fc_order = Cells(3, 4)
Set fc_alphabet = Cells(3, 8)

fc_order = "order of appearance"
For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  If i Mod 30 = 0 Then
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=fc_order.Offset(i - 1, -2), Address:="", _
  SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(TOC).Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="TOP"
  End If
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i + 2, 4), Address:="", _
SubAddress:=Worksheets(i).Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(i).Name
Next i

fc_alphabet = "alphabetically"
Range(fc_order.Offset(1, 0), fc_order.End(xlDown)).Copy fc_alphabet.Offset(1, 0)
Range(fc_alphabet.Offset(1, 0), fc_alphabet.End(xlDown)).Sort Key1:=fc_alphabet.Offset(1, 0)

If MsgBox("Do you want a hyperlink to " & TOC & " on each sheet in cell A1 ?" & Chr(10) & _
"(if cell A1 is empty)", 36, "Hyperlink on each sheet") = vbYes Then
  For Each sht In Worksheets
  sht.Select
  If Cells(1, 1) = "" And sht.Name <> TOC Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(1, 1), Address:="", _
  SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(TOC).Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="TOC"
  Next sht
End If

Sheets(TOC).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The script below is similar, but somewhat different, to the one above.

```
Sub BuildTOC()
  'listed from active cell down 7-cols --  DMcRitchie 1999-08-14 2000-09-05
  Dim iSheet As Long, iBefore As Long
  Dim sSheetName As String, sActiveCell As String
  Dim cRow As Long, cCol As Long, cSht As Long
  Dim lastcell
  Dim qSht As String
  Dim mg As String
  Dim rg As Range
  Dim CRLF As String
  Dim Reply As Variant
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  cRow = ActiveCell.Row
  cCol = ActiveCell.Column
  sSheetName = UCase(ActiveSheet.Name)
  sActiveCell = UCase(ActiveCell.Value)
  mg = ""
  CRLF = Chr(10)  'Actually just CR
  Set rg = Range(Cells(cRow, cCol), Cells(cRow - 1 + ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count, cCol + 7))
  rg.Select
  If sSheetName <> "$$TOC" Then mg = mg & "Sheetname is not $$TOC" & CRLF
  If sActiveCell <> "$$TOC" Then mg = mg & "Selected cell value is not $$TOC" & CRLF
  If mg <> "" Then
     mg = "Warning BuildTOC will destructively rewrite the selected area" _
     & CRLF & CRLF & mg & CRLF & "Press OK to proceed, " _
      & "the affected area will be rewritten, or" & CRLF & _
      "Press CANCEL to check area then reinvoke this macro (BuildTOC)"
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True  'make range visible
     Reply = MsgBox(mg, vbOKCancel, "Create TOC for " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count _
      & " items in workbook" & Chr(10) & "revised will now occupy up to 10 columns")
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     If Reply <> 1 Then GoTo AbortCode
  End If
  rg.Clear      'Clear out any previous hyperlinks, fonts, etc in the area
  For cSht = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol) = "'" & Sheets(cSht).Name
     If TypeName(Sheets(cSht)) = "Worksheet" Then
        'hypName = "'" & Sheets(csht).Name
        ' qSht = Replace(Sheets(cSht).Name, """", """""") -- replace not in XL97
        qSht = Application.Substitute(Sheets(cSht).Name, """", """""")
        If CDbl(Application.Version) < 8# Then
          '-- use next line for XL95
          Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 2) = "'" & Sheets(cSht).Name  'XL95
        Else
          '-- Only for XL97, XL98, XL2000 -- will create hyperlink & codename
          Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 2) = "'" & Sheets(cSht).CodeName

          '--- excel is not handling lots of objects well ---
          'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol), _
          '  Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheets(cSht).Name & "'!A1"
          '--- so will use the HYPERLINK formula instead ---
          '--- =HYPERLINK("[VLOOKUP.XLS]'$$TOC'!A1","$$TOC")
          ActiveSheet.Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol).Formula = _
            "=hyperlink(""[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name _
            & "]'" & qSht & "'!A1"",""" & qSht & """)"
        End If
     Else
       Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 2) = "'" & Sheets(cSht).Name
     End If
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 1) = TypeName(Sheets(cSht))
    ' -- activate next line to include content of cell A1 for each sheet
    ' Cells(cRow - 1 + csht, cCol + 3) = Sheets(Sheets(csht).Name).Range("A1").Value
     On Error Resume Next
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 6) = Sheets(cSht).ScrollArea '.Address(0, 0)
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 7) = Sheets(cSht).PageSetup.PrintArea
     If TypeName(Sheets(cSht)) <> "Worksheet" Then GoTo byp7
     Set lastcell = Sheets(cSht).Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 4) = lastcell.Address(0, 0)
     Cells(cRow - 1 + cSht, cCol + 5) = lastcell.Column * lastcell.Row
byp7: 'xxx
     On Error GoTo 0
  Next cSht

  'Now sort the results:  2. Type(D), 1. Name (A), 3. module(unsorted)
  rg.Sort Key1:=rg.Cells(1, 2), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=rg.Cells(1, 1) _
      , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  rg.Columns.AutoFit
  rg.Select           'optional
  'if cells above range are blank want these headers
  ' Worksheet,   Type,    codename
  If cRow > 1 Then
     If "" = Trim(Cells(cRow - 1, cCol) & Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 1) & Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 2)) Then
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol) = "Worksheet"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 1) = "Type"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 2) = "CodeName"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 3) = "[opt.]"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 4) = "Lastcell"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 5) = "cells"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 6) = "ScrollArea"
        Cells(cRow - 1, cCol + 7) = "PrintArea"
     End If
  End If
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Reply = MsgBox("Table of Contents created." & CRLF & CRLF & _
     "Would you like the tabs in workbook also sorted", _
     vbOKCancel, "Option to Sort " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count _
     & " tabs in workbook")
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'If Reply = 1 Then SortALLSheets  'Invoke macro to Sort Sheet Tabs
  Sheets(sSheetName).Activate
AbortCode:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
Sub BuildTOC_A3()
   Cells(3, 1).Select
   BuildTOC
End Sub
```